# Looking for polling software or website that sends out reminders and results at poll conclusion

Tags: polls

I'm looking for a polling app or site that can

1. Send out the poll question to a persisted group of users
2. Automatically send out the conclusion of the poll at a preset time
3. Regularly do this recurrently automatically.

For example. Let's say I have an organized basketball game every Sunday at 2 PM, but it only occurs if we know at least 8 people will show up. I want the app to automatically send out an email (or message via WhatsApp or other app) on every Friday at 2:00 PM, a reminder again every Sunday morning at 10:00 AM (including the current poll status), and then a final result again at noon on every Sunday.

I looked at https://pollunit.com/, which had been suggested in the answers to other polling questions, but I don't think it has features 2 and 3.